# Problema ao criar chave estrangeira no entity

Tags: entity-framework, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando criar uma *primary key* composta, até tudo bem. Com isso preciso fazer uma *foreign key* composta.

Tenho mais ou menos o seguinte cenário (é um cenário hipotético mas reflete o que preciso e meu erro):

```
public class Keys {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key_2 { get; set; }

    // order is important here as defined in "KeyAuthorities" table
    [ForeignKey("KeyAuthorities", Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("KeyAuthorities", Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

}

public class KeyAuthorities {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

}
```

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'KeyAuthorities' on type
>   'PortalAdmCC.Models.Keys' is not valid. The foreign key name
>   'KeyAuthorities' was not found on the dependent type
>   'PortalAdmCC.Models.Keys'. The Name value should be a comma separated
>   list of foreign key property names.

O que esse erro quer dizer?

Comment: Parece que faltou fechar o parenteses do ForeignKey. O erro indica que você não tem a propriedade de navegação com nome "KeyAuthorities" na class "Key"

Comment: O que isso quer dizer basicamente?

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta. Não sei se a segunda forma realmente funciona. Não uso modelo com FK composta.

Answer (score 0):

O erro indica que o EF não encontrou a propriedade com o nome que você definiu como FK na anotação.

Você pode tentar adicionando uma propriedade de navegação para a FK:

```
public class Keys {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key_2 { get; set; }

    // order is important here as defined in "KeyAuthorities" table
    [ForeignKey("Authorities")]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Authorities")]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

    public KeyAuthorities Authorities { get; set; }
}

public class KeyAuthorities {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

}
```

A outra opção de especificar a FK com as anotações seria anotar a propriedade de navegação com o nomes dos campos que forma a FK:

```
public class Keys {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key_2 { get; set; }

    // order is important here as defined in "KeyAuthorities" table
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("KeyAuthorities_Key_1, KeyAuthorities_Key_2")]
    public KeyAuthorities Authorities { get; set; }
}

public class KeyAuthorities {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyAuthorities_Key_2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro, tanto das duas formas, e teoricamente estou colocando mapa de navegação para a FK

Comment: Mesmo erro é estranho. Eu coloquei outro nome para a FK que agora é uma propriedade na classe.

Comment: Esse ForeingKey tem como parametro o nome da classe que referencia ela ne?

Comment: Tipo, tenho que indicar o nome do arquivo ou o nome da foreign key?

Comment: Não. Ele tem o nome do atributo ou o nome da propriedade de navegação. Quando é referenciado na classe pai, precisa estar em uma coleção. [Esse tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) deve te ajudar a entender melhor como configurar a FK.

Comment: Vamos abrir um chat e te explico melhor a situação?

Comment: Pode ser assim? Fica mais fácil de te explicar

Comment: Eu abrir um projeto novo aqui e coloquei essas classes da opção 2 e ele gerou as tabelas com as FKs compostas. Tente fazer isso primeiro para eliminar outros problemas que exista no seu modelo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73914/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-pagotti).

Comment: Não sei se é algum bloqueio, mas o chat abre só como leitura para mim.

Comment: reita, que estranho